# Iteration counter for double loops

Tags: python, algorithm, nested-loops

I am trying to find the formula to count every iteration of this double `for` loop (in python for instance):

```
for i in range(5):
   for j in range(5):
       count = MYSTERIOUS_FORMULA
       print count
```

Here the final value of count should be 25.

I tried `count=(i+1)*j` but it produce `0,1,2,3,4,0,2,4` etc.

Comment: You need to initialise `count` outside the inner loop, you're resetting it every time you iterate in the outer loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Double-for-loop (a.k.a. Nested loops).**

```
# Set count to 0 before loop starts
count = 0

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        # solved mysterious formula (short hand 'count = count + 1')
        count += 1
# displaying count after loop
print(count)
```

Expanding on the formula `count = count + 1`, this sets `count` to be `equal` itself + `1`:

```
count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 11):

The mysterious formula is quite simple:

```
{count} = {index of current loop} + {size of current loop}*{count of parent loop}
```

As an example, consider a single loop:

```
x = 5

for i in range(x):
    count = i
```

To be explicit, `count = i + x*0` but the second term is irrelevant because there is no parent loop.  An example of two loops might be more illuminating:

```
x = 5
y = 6

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        count = j + y*(i)
```

Notice that I put `i` in parentheses to emphasize that it is the `{count of parent loop}`.  This formula can be easily expanded to a third loop:

```
x = 5
y = 6
z = 7

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        for k in range(z):
            count = k + z*(j + y*(i))
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compute the number in each iteration:

```
for i in range(5):
   for j in range(5):
       count = 5*i+j+1
       print count
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
from itertools import product

for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(product(range(5), range(5)), 1):
    print(idx, i, j)
```

which prints:

```
1 0 0
2 0 1
3 0 2
4 0 3
5 0 4
[...]
24 4 3
25 4 4
```